# Why does passing a class as parameter requires a default constructor?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, initialization, default-constructor

I define an object LogManager taking a custom struct as constructor parameter:

```
typedef struct{
    ...
} logSettings;

class LogManager
{
    public:
    LogManager(logSettings logsettings);
};
```

I then define another object taking a LogManager as parameter:

```
class Core
{
    private:
    LogManager m_logmanager;

    public:
    Core(LogManager logmanager);
};

Core::Core(LogManager logmanager){//error here
    m_logmanager = logmanager;
}
```

My IDE gives me the error "no default constructor exists for class "LogManager"". 
It's True, but why do I need a default constructor? logmanager already is of type LogManager(). When I call my constructor Core(LogManager logmanager), logmanager's constructor is supposed to already have been called. I'm not attempting to create a new object, just get a reference to an existing LogManager.

What am I missing? I'm fairly new to C++.

Answer (score 4):

The problem does not relate to passing an object as an argument ro a function or a constructor. The problem is that you have defined the data member `m_logmanager`

```
class Core
{
    private:
    LogManager m_logmanager;

    public:
    Core(LogManager logmanager);
};
```

and it is created using the default constructor before the body of the constructor of the class `Core` gets the control.

Write the constructor like

```
Core::Core(LogManager logmanager) : m_logmanager( logmanager )
{
}
```

And it is even better to declare it like

```
Core::Core( const LogManager &logmanager) : m_logmanager( logmanager )
{
}
```

Comment: That would not work either because `LogManager` don't have copy nor move constructor, would it ? The only constructor defined in `LogManager` use a `LogSettings` parameter

Comment: @DrosvarG For starters the compiler creates a default copy constructor.

Comment: It would be better to write it like `Core::Core(LogManager logmanager) : m_logmanager(std::move(logmanager)) {}`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes. But new questions will be arise.:)